# Batch file that can read and process its own output in realtime?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which runs a python script. The python script after completion sends a number like shown below:
I need my batch file to read its own output as it runs and then use this (the number 3 shown in figure below to do some processing
Is this possible with batch?

[image: batch file output]
EDITED FOR CLARITY:

[image]

I want to have a script which uses "net use" command.
The output from this specific command is as shown below... which will be printed to cmd window in which script is running ! Now I want my script to read this output ..like if a certain address is found in the already mapped drives list it will do something..like unmap the drive

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show the code you have. You should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try `for /F %%a in ('python "whatever.py"') do set "result=%%a"`. See `for /?` for more details.

Comment: I guess one who read the question properly would find it sufficient. I'm not having an example specific question if you see..its a general question reframed here for you - is it possible to create a batch script which can read what you can see on screen as the batch file runs? PS: I cant share the original code here for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand quite well what your purpose is, what has to do `python` to do with capture the `net use` command output?

As a rule of thumb, to capture any command output, you must use a `for` loop (i.e. here capturing clipboard content using `powershell`

```
rem get clipboard content into variable
set "psCmd=powershell -Command "add-type -an system.windows.forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText()""
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%# in (`%psCmd%`) do set "clipContent=%%#"
```

So, in order to grab the output of `net use`

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=6 tokens=2,3" %%a in ('net use') do (
  echo/%%a | find ":">NUL && echo/Drive letter %%a - Remote name %%b
)
exit/B
```

But, I suggest that you better use `wmic` (following two are similar)

```
@echo off
for /f "useback skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (`"wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType="4" get DeviceID, ProviderName"`) do (
  echo/%%a | find ":">NUL && echo/Drive letter %%a - Remote name %%b
)
exit/B
```

or

```
@echo off
for /f "useback skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (`"wmic path Win32_MappedLogicalDisk get DeviceID, ProviderName"`) do (
  echo/%%a | find ":">NUL && echo/Drive letter %%a - Remote name %%b
)
exit/B
```

Since, you may add the `/node:"some_other_computer_name"` switch to `wmic` and may list mapped drives from any computer on the net, i.e

```
@echo off
for /f "useback skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (`"wmic /node:"hp-ml110" path Win32_MappedLogicalDisk Where DriveType="4" get DeviceID, ProviderName"`) do (
  echo/%%a | find ":">NUL && echo/Drive letter %%a - Remote name %%b
)
exit/B
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thnx! this is what i was looking for ! Although I'm yet to follow fully your alternative ways of doing the same. FYI : I used ur second listed code and it works. thnx! I shall comprehend  the others fully soon!